# Monthly Date on X-Axis in Wavelet Analysis

Tags: date, wavelet, x-axis, wavelet-transform, biwavelet

I am performing Wavelet Analysis using biwavelet package in R. The date variable does not have continuous dates but with gaps. The data is monthly data. I tried two formats of data, the monthly date format from stata, and the normal date function that shows the end-of-month date every time. When I try to create the graph using a date variable showing end-of-month dates, I get the following error.

```
Error in check.datum(d) :  The step size must be constant (see approx function to interpolate)
```

When I used mdate variable, that is monthly date variable created through stata, I only see some numbers like 670, 700, etc on X-Axis. I want month and year to be shown on X-Axis.

An MWE is given below:

```
library(foreign)
library(biwavelet)
library(xts)
library(labelled)
library(zoo)

date =c("2020-02-28", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-30", "2020-10-31", "2020-11-30", "2020-12-31", "2021-01-31", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-31", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-30", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-30")
rdate = as.Date(date)
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
date
class(date)
var = c(-0.077423148, -0.083293147, -0.089214072, -0.095185943, -0.101208754, -0.107282504, -0.113407195, -0.119582824, -0.125809386, -0.125806898, -0.132149309, -0.138584509,  -0.145112529, -0.151733354, -0.158446968, -0.165253401, -0.172152638, -0.179144681, -0.186229542, -0.193407193, -0.200677648, -0.208040923)
data = data.frame(date, var)
View(data)
X <- as.xts(data[,-1], order.by = date)
ABC <- data.frame(date, var)
wt.t1=plot(wt(ABC), form = "%b-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried one thing and it worked. I changed the end of month date to start of month date and month - year started showing on X-Axis.

Comment: can you provide an example of the code used to fix the issue you were having?